# I do not know why these Prepared Statements code generate Errors

Tags: java, jdbc

NetBeans is my Java Programming editor. I wrote the following JDBC Prepared Statements code. The code compiled well but it generated errors when I ran it. I have checked all my Java books; none has example on using NetBeans to program application that uses JDBC Prepared Statements I need help.

Here is the code:

```
private void editButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{                                               
    String sql = "Update Products SET"
            + "Description = ?, "
            + "Price = ? "
            + "Where Code = ?";
    try
    {
        pstmt.setString(1, "CODE");
        pstmt.setString(2, "DESCRIPTION");
        pstmt.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble("PRICE"));

        int rowUpdated = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rowUpdated > 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "record updated successfully");
        }
        // Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Product.this, e.getMessage());
    }
}                                          

private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
{                                                 

}                                            

private void cancelButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
{                                                 

}                                            

private void acceptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                             
{                                                 
    try
    {
        String sql = "Insert into PRODUCTS(CODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE)"
                + "Values(?, ?, ?)";
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1, codeTextField.getText());
        pstmt.setString(2, descriptionTextField.getText());
        pstmt.setDouble(3, Double.parseDouble("Price"));

        int rowInserted = pstmt.executeUpdate();

        if (rowInserted > 0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null, "A new user was inserted successfully!");
        }

        // Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Product.this, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You say this program "generated errors" when run - pelase [edit] your post to be more specific.  You should quote the actual error messages exactly (preferably using
copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

add a space after the "SET"

```
String sql = "Update Products SET "
            + "Description = ?, "
            + "Price = ? "
            + "Where Code = ?";
```

and eventually a space before "values"

```
String sql = "Insert into PRODUCTS(CODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE)"
            + " Values(?, ?, ?)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems with spaces in your query, also when you are setting the values, the order should be Descripcion, Price and Code. Something like this:

```
 private void editButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
 {                                               
    String sql = "Update Products SET Description = ?, Price = ? "
       + "where Code = ?";
    try
    {
        pstmt.setString(1, "DESCRIPTION");
        pstmt.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble("PRICE"));
        pstmt.setString(3, "CODE");

        int rowUpdated = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if (rowUpdated == 1)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "record updated successfully");
        }
        // Clean-up environment
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Product.this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```